# Setting the background using a JLabel and an image inserted into it

Tags: java, background, imageicon

I've been working on a small project for fun, i'm currently working on the background however it is really small, to change this i'm setting the dimensions to the max screen size (the project is full screen)

```
    public void setBackground(JLabel bg) {

    bg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Background.gif")));

    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int width = (int) d.getWidth();
    int height = (int) d.getHeight();
    bg.setSize(width, height);
    add(bg);

}
```

However, it does increase the JLabel size but not the actual image size, why is this?

EDIT:

i've found a way to do this, but it doesn't seem to find the specified path! i had made a resources folder where it is stored (a source folder in eclipse) i put it in there but it can't read the input file.

```
    public void setBackground(JLabel bg) {
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Background.gif"));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ImageIcon imgi = new ImageIcon(fitimage(img, bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight()));

    bg.setIcon(imgi);

    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int width = (int) d.getWidth();
    int height = (int) d.getHeight();
    bg.setSize(width, height);
    add(bg);

}

private Image fitimage(Image img , int w , int h) {
    BufferedImage resizedimage = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = resizedimage.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0,w,h,null);
    g2.dispose();
    return resizedimage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to resize your image first before using it in your application. It must be the same size as your label. Whatever the actual size of your image is, that's the size Java will display it as and will not auto-resize it respectively to your label

Comment: Would converting it to a regular image, then resizing it, then changing it back into an image icon and applying it to the label work?

Comment: You don't need to convert it, leave it as an image icon, just ensure that the format stays the same. I would suggest using paint.net (it's free from Microsoft) as it will only alter the size of the image and not affect any of its other properties like normal MS paint would do.

Comment: I've found out what i could use to resize it, but it can't find the image now, it is in the resources folder which is a source folder.

Comment: Looking at the code you used, that is taking a very long route to achieve what you want to do. Just resize it using paint.net so all you have to do is call up the image from a Java package in your project. It's a million times quicker and easier. Keep it simple and straight forward and you will have less problems.

Comment: But the thing is, what if i wanted to make it fullscreen at some point? each screen size is different